# How can we fake landscape erosion?

Tags: texturing

Blender's landscape fractals are pretty basic but erosion, as from decades of rain, can increase appearances drastically.

Have you 'successfully' - a relative term here - eroded your geometry using/mixing textures or shaders?

Answer (score 0):

Not super realistically. I have an approach at this, which involves taking the slope and cavity to create an erosion-like displacement effect, but this is not really how erosion works. As far as I know, the only truly realistic way to attack this project is with actual coding. Heres an addon you could check out: https://www.blendermarket.com/products/erosion-add-on